# Unity 3D not working no longer works after update

Tags: unity, compiz, 11.10

I've been using Oneric since the first beta version, and I'm using it on my Acer 5810TG laptop. Recently, though I don't know which day exactly, after performing routine updates from legit PPAs, Ubuntu started with Unity 2D only. Even if I pick "Ubuntu" or "User defined session" on the login screen, Unity-2D loads.
I have built-in Intel graphics which always worked fine with Unity 3D, both on early versions of oneric and on natty.

Please suggest any possible reasons and/or ways to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try installing the latest version of the drivers for your graphics.

A ppa with the newest drivers can [be found here](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver).

Add it with

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

install the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` using the command

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Comment: np, glad to help!

Comment: Can this driver be used with NVIDIA chipset as well?

Comment: @subeh.sharma no, intel.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the PPA already mentioned by Bruno, there is another PPA by Fabio Pedretti with  newer drivers than the Stefan Glasenhardt PPA. This PPA also contains newer ATI and nVidia drivers, so it's been a good all in one solution for me. I did have broken Intel graphics as he upgraded the PPA from Mesa 7.x to 8.x in January, but he fixed the issue quickly.

More info here: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers

Add it with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers 
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my intel i7 integrated graphics card:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
Error: GLX is not available on the system
```

It turned out some nvidia packages got installed somehow:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

After removing every package with "nvidia" in it, it worked again.